# Can I interrupt quarantine to go get the 2nd dose of the vaccine after coming back from an amber list-country?

Tags: uk, international-travel, covid-19, quarantine, vaccinations

From [here](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control) I read

> If you have been in a country or territory on the:
>
> - [...]
> - amber list - you must quarantine in the place you’re staying and take 2 COVID-19 tests

This makes me think I can't leave the house, not even to only go to the place where I can get the 2nd dose of the vaccine.

I'm asking anyway to understand if that's the case or not.

Comment: The vaccination centre is going to ask you if you have experienced any symptoms, have you been exposed etc etc. What if you have been infected? Are you willing to wipe out everyone who is trying to get a vaccine?

Comment: @stackoverblown well, OP has been in an "amber list country", but they did not say that they "experienced any symptoms", and there is no evidence that they "have been exposed". In particular, many of the countries in the Amber list (e.g.:Germany) are an order of magnitude **safer** in COVID terms than just being in the UK. So yes, OP would be breaking a rule, but no, they would not be putting people at risk more than a person that was in the UK the last two weeks. The "moral" argument just does not hold here.

Comment: @wimi But he/she must have been travelling through airports where lots of people moving through. You have no idea where these other people have been.

Comment: For what it's worth, my vaccination booking confirmation e-mail from the NHS says this: "If you think you have symptoms of coronavirus or you have recently been told you need to isolate you should not attend your appointment and will need to book again."

Comment: The *actual* issue here are not (only) the official regulations. What *do you think* would be the right thing to do? That puzzled me with some acquaintances: "Hey, let's go to a museum quick before they close them again because of the quickly rising infection rate!" The challenge at hand is not to find loopholes in regulations but to be responsible. The regulations are for the stupid people.

Comment: Considering that it's perfectly ok to move from one country to another even 48 hours after taking a test, which means that between you and spreading the virus there's 2 days + 1 or more airports, I don't have an idea of what it's right in this case.

Comment: @stackoverblown and why is Australia on the green list then? Traveling from Australia to the UK surely requires a much longer time in airports, with people that may have been everywhere. It is obvious that these lists are not made only with health concerns in mind. Actually, using your argument, there would not be a green list at all, as traveling from almost any country to the UK requires going through airports!

Comment: @stackoverblown - That's kind of an appropriate username. I would say it is indeed somewhat *overblown* to say that anyone, especially a partially-vaccinated person with no symptoms who will likely have been quarantining for at least a few days, is likely to "wipe out everyone who is trying to get a vaccine." One could look at some studies of transmission in airplanes before widespread mask use to confirm that even with absolutely no protections, several hours of contact, and very close proximity, it is unlikely that a single person will infect everyone near them.

Comment: See [here](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamanetworkopen/fullarticle/2769383) and [here](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/article/26/11/20-3299_article). Part of intelligently managing the risks of COVID-19, or any other disease, has to include accurately quantifying them.

Comment: not an actual answer, but I had the same doubt, and I moved my appointment before going to the amber country. I think moving your appointment either before leaving or after quarantine (whichever make sense in your scenario) it's the safest bet, both legally and not to put other at risk, especially if you'll be flying

Comment: Even in the *improbable* case that they are indeed infected, the likelihood of them infecting a single person (to say nothing of "wiping out everyone") during a 15 minute window where they and everyone else should be wearing face masks is likely low. Consider [this case study](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/69/wr/mm6928e2.htm) of COVID-19 transmission (or lack thereof) in a hair salon with a mask policy. It is possibly less dangerous for a masked person who has traveled in the last few days to get a vaccine than for a person who has never left Britain to eat at a restaurant for 2 hours.

Comment: Also, UK quarantine guidance in general does *not* seem to be based on up-to-date research on COVID-19, and I doubt any sort of cost-benefit analysis with vaccines was taken into account (or any probabilistic calculation at all, really). To give an idea, according to the guidelines: "You cannot leave the place where you’re quarantining to walk your dog" (outdoor transmission, particularly with masks and in non-crowded areas, has been determined to be quite low), but you can "travel to a COVID-19 testing site" (a slightly higher-risk activity, which, rather obviously, may not change anything).

Comment: @Obie Please google Typhoid Mary and super-spreader. When you say unlikely, are you basing it on facts/science or your wishful thinking?

Comment: @stackoverblown - That is not a response to a detailed argument based in research, but rather more of a research prompt.

Comment: @stackoverblown - I don't know, but *one* of us cited three studies. I could turn the question around: are you assuming that UK quarantine guidelines are based on up-to-date facts/science rather than a combination of political needs, speculative guidance from the beginning of the pandemic and early research that has been superseded, and a "better safe than sorry" attitude?

Comment: But perhaps you want *more* research? Perhaps you want to be sure that [having received one dose](https://www.bbc.com/news/health-56904993) of common mRNA vaccines reduces the risk of transmission by more than the difference in new case rates per capita between the UK and several amber list countries? Perhaps you also want to know if the UK currently has more cases per day than some countries on the amber list (yes).

Comment: Perhaps knowing the [percentage of people returning from amber list countries who even have COVID](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/jun/22/ministers-may-relax-englands-rules-for-returnees-from-amber-list-countries) is also useful?

Answer (score 38):

No. When I went to get vaccinated recently in the UK I was explicitly asked if there was any reason I should be self-isolating, presumably with the result that if I had said "yes" I would have been turned away (or worse!).

Given the fact that there's a large time window for you getting your second dose I don't see that there's any necessity to get it during your quarantine.

Comment: I believe the recommended window for second dose in the UK is 8-12 weeks, which is far longer than quarantines 2 weeks (or is it 10 days now?). There will still be plenty of appointments and vaccine available when the quarantine period has completed, so you should contact the vaccination clinic and rearrange as soon as possible (so they can give the original slot and dose to someone else).

Comment: @afaulconbridge It is 10 days now.

Comment: @spikey_richie with early release if you pay for tests.

Answer (score 25):

To me, that seems to be correct. But for certainty, you should call the medical centre where you wish to be vaccinated.

The quarantine procedure is set out in more detail on [this page](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-quarantine-when-you-arrive-in-england). The most relevant sections seem to be:

> **Going out**
> Unless you’re at risk of harm, you cannot leave the premises where you’re in quarantine. You must only exercise inside the place where you’re quarantining or in the garden. You cannot leave the place where you’re quarantining to walk your dog. You will need to ask friends or relatives to help you with this.

and:

> **Exceptional circumstances**
> You can leave your accommodation in certain exceptional circumstances. This includes needing to:
>
> - get basic urgent necessities like food and medicines where you cannot arrange for these to be delivered
> - travel to a COVID-19 testing site
> - access critical public services including social services and services provided to victims (such as victims of crime)
> - move to a different place for quarantine where you can no longer remain where you are
>
> There may be other exceptional circumstances that allow you to leave your place of quarantine.
>
> You could get advice from a medical or other professional to help decide whether your circumstances are exceptional and require you to leave your place of quarantine.
>
> Even if you have an exception, you must continue to follow the general restrictions that apply.

In short: it is only permitted to leave your place of quarantine in "exceptional circumstances". There's (unsurprisingly) no exhaustive list of what qualifies as "exceptional circumstances", but several examples are given. The given examples (it's impossible or unsafe to remain where you are, you need food/medicine and it can't be delivered, accessing services for victims of crime, complying with legal obligations) all seem to fall broadly into the category of "emergency".

There is a mention of getting medicine which can’t be delivered at home, but I don’t believe that exception would be applicable to a COVID vaccination. The reason being that the exception is to

> **get basic urgent necessities** like food and medicines where you cannot arrange for these to be delivered

(emphasis added). The phrase “basic urgent necessities” leads me to believe this medicine exception applies specifically to obtaining medicine somebody *needs* (for example, to manage an existing condition). While I fully encourage everybody to get vaccinated as soon as they can, I find it extremely difficult to imagine a covid vaccination would be considered an “urgent necessity” for anybody outside of specific high risk groups.

However, as I said at the start of the answer (and as suggested in the guidance), you can call the medical centre responsible for your vaccination and take advice from a medical professional. I very much expect they'll advise you to arrange to receive the second dose after your quarantine period ends, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126833/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-h-can-i-interrupt-quarantine-to-go-get-the-2nd-dos). Please go to that room to add more comments.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, referring to guidance (as linked to in other answers) can certainly be useful but you need to be careful as guidance does not generally carry the weight of law and often uses paraphrasing which can lead to subtle inaccuracies. If you want to be sure it's always best to refer directly to the legislation.

Secondly, there is no such thing as a "UK" jurisdiction when it comes to law, so the exact answer depends on where you have arrived from abroad. The UK is made up of four jurisdictions: England, Wales, Northern Ireland, and Scotland. Any given law could apply to any combination of those.

The relevant law here for *England* is the [Health Protection (Coronavirus, International Travel and Operator Liability) (England) Regulations 2021](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2021/582/contents).

[Regulation 9](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2021/582/regulation/9) provides that when you arrive in England from a so-called "amber" country (a "category 2" country in the regulations) you must usually self-isolate. Some people are exempt but I'll assume that is not applicable here.

Regulation 9(11) provides the list of exceptions to the requirement to self-isolate. I won't copy the entire list here (you can click the link above to see it), but suffice to say there is no specific exception for obtaining a 2nd dose of a vaccine. The following medical exception is available, but it's hard too see that a 2nd dose could be considered urgent or that you will be able to get a doctor's advice that you cannot wait until the self-isolation period has ended:

Regulation 9(11)(b): *"to seek medical assistance, where this is required urgently or on the advice of a registered medical practitioner, including to access services from dentists, opticians, audiologists, chiropodists, chiropractors, osteopaths and other medical or health practitioners, including services relating to mental health"*

There is also a catch-all "exceptional circumstances" provision at regulation 9(11)(i). This means that you can break your self-isolation for *any* reason (including one which isn't specifically mentioned) provided that it constitutes exceptional circumstances. Whether it does or not would be a matter for the courts to decide if it came to that. The regulation gives some (non-exhaustive) examples of what might constitute exceptional circumstances. One of them is:

*"to obtain basic necessities such as food and medical supplies for those in the same household (including any pets or animals in the household) where it is not possible to obtain these provisions in any other manner"*

The problem here is similar to the first exception: it is hard to imagine that a 2nd dose is exceptional circumstances or even basic "necessities" since there is no compelling reason you can't just wait a few extra days to get it.

As a side note, the above is a good example of where guidance can be inaccurate. From [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/166383/13208) you can see that the guidance says *"get basic urgent necessities like food and medicines where you cannot arrange for these to be delivered"*, but as you can see the actual rule is wider than that - you need to be unable to obtain the necessity in *any other manner*, not just from a delivery.